# Axios with Vue - How to replace endpoint array with new array

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I have created a JSON file with an array of objects as shown below:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "type": "input",
    "title": "What is your dog's name?",
    "value": ""
  }
]
```

The endpoint to this array of objects is http://localhost:3000/questions.

I have a Vue form which I am looping through and binding v-model to the value property. Eventually I'll have an object for each question so 6 questions = 6 objects.

When the user submits the form I simply want to replace this array of objects with a brand new array of objects (effectively the same array but with the value properties filled out by the user)

I've tried this:

```
async updateQuestions({ state }) {
  await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/questions", state.questions);
},
```

and get this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "type": "input",
    "title": "What is your dog's name?",
    "value": ""
  },
  [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "type": "input",
      "title": "What is your dog's name?",
      "value": "dd"
    }
  ]
]
```

I don't want to append to the existing array but replace it:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "type": "input",
    "title": "What is your dog's name?",
    "value": "dd"
  }
]
```

How can this be done with Axios? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has had a similar issue, the problem occurred because the 'questions' array needed to be placed inside a single root object.

bad:

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "type": "input",
    "title": "What is your dog's name?",
    "value": ""
  }
]
```

good:

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "type": "input",
      "title": "What is your dog's name?",
      "value": ""
    }
  ]
}
```